# Doing a where x in (select y from tbl.A )

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables.

tbl.A has a list of doctors and their patients (as in patients who have that doctor as primary care physician). No patient has more than 1 doctor assigned.

```
 Doctor       Patients 
   x             a
   x             b
   y             c
   y             d
```

tbl.B has a list of the doctors and all patients they met with in the past year (A doctor can meet with any patient, whether that patient has that doctor as PCP or not)

TableB:

```
   Doctor    Date          Saw_Patient
     R        05-01-2015        x
     R        05-01-2015        y
     S        02-05-2015        g
     S        06-06-2015        x
```

I essentially want to add a column to tbl.B to add an indicator signifying if the doctor is the PCP for that patient

```
Doctor    Patient     PCP of Patient
  A          z             Yes
  A          x             No
  B          j             Yes
  B          i             Yes
```

How can I easily do this.  Is something like this possible or am I missing something?

```
select  b.doctor
       ,b.patient
       ,case when b.patient in (select patient from tblA where a.doctor=b.doctor) then 1 else 0 end as PCP
 from         tblA a
 inner join   tblB b
    on a.doctor=b.doctor
```

Comment: Please share table schema

Comment: What happened when you ran that query?

Comment: It probably only returned PCPs and always with an answer of "yes".

Comment: Haven't run it yet because server is down.  I'm just trying to be ready for when it's back up.

Comment: I'm thinking I might not even need the join.  I can do  'from tblB' and just keep the tblA part in the subquery.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  I was also thinking that this might be a bad idea because a patient might change primary care providers.

Comment: Well, this is for a point in time, so that won't be an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need an outer join:

```
SELECT  b.doctor
       ,b.patient
       ,CASE WHEN a.doctor IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PCP
 FROM        tblB b
 LEFT JOIN   tblA a
    ON a.doctor=b.doctor
   AND a.patient = b.patient
```

Comment: Jesus, I shoudl have been able to think of this.  Thank you!